# How to filter Pandas DataFrame rows by checking inclusion in cell's element which is a list?

Tags: pandas

Given a dataframe where one of the columns looks like this, how would I filter the dataframe down to only rows where this column's element contains a c anywhere in its list?

```
df['orderings']
1     (a, a, a, a)
10    (a, a, c, c)
12    (a, a, c, b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your a,b,c are all strings, you can do:

```
df[df["orderings"].apply(lambda l: "a" in l and "c" in l)]
```

Comment: Ah apply! Great! I ended up using a pretty hacky loop to do it, but i will go replace with this. Thanks :)